# Can't send non English Words to Select Statement

Tags: android, database, sqlite

```
SQLiteDatabase myDatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("SMDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
Cursor c = myDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT PName FROM tbl_staff WHERE PMajor LIKE '%" + selectedItemFromSpin + "%'", null);
c.moveToFirst();
```

This is my code, now this code works fine when I pass an English Word for selectedItemFromSpin variable but when I send a non English word like "نوشته مثال" then app crashes and says a message with button named force to quit.

I appreciate if anyone helps.

Comment: Wonder if it would work better as a parameterized query.

Comment: Almost certainly would.  This way is asking for an SQL injection.

Comment: Well if it's a local database within an Android app, SQL vulnerabilities might not matter, unless the data could potentially come from other users.  Either way, it's not good practice to build SQL queries from string concatenation.

Comment: My Database is in Assets Folder and I have a class that Copies Database into /data/data/.../databases/ folder. so when I want to use it I just call it by name. The second thing is when I open database ,in the code I mention to debugger that it opens database in mode of "MODE_PRIVATE".

Comment: So what would be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{"%"+selectionArgs[0]+"%","%"+selectionArgs[2]+ "%"});